# How to create Jar library file which automatically creates rest api endpoints to a spring boot application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to create a library jar file. When I bring that to a spring-boot application it should make the application to have Rest API endpoints, without adding any @RestController to the spring-boot application.

For example, I want to create `custom-oauth.jar` library. When I include the `custom-oauth.jar` to the spring-boot application, the application should have `http://localhost/token` and `http://localhost/validate` ... etc.

I know this is a very common case for spring applications, and there are so many jar files which does this, but I can't find how to implement that in the Spring documentation.

Where should I start reading and what tools I should use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this in a Boot application is to [write your own autoconfiguration module](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html). In short, you create one or more "bootstrap" `@Configuration` classes and list them in `META-INF/spring.factories`. They can then do whatever sort of operations you'd normally do (like registering `@Bean`s or `@ComponentScan`s for controller classes included in the jar).